# Why is my Command Prompt in Visual Studio Code not using the nerd font I use?

Tags: terminal, fonts, visual-studio-code

Ok, so I was going to code so I opened vscode, but for some reason, my terminal font turned into monospace, even tho my settings for the terminal font was still the same.

My font is MesloLGM Nerd Font Mono, since I use `oh-my-posh`, I have to use a nerd font.

I can still use my terminal, but it just doesn't feel right to use my terminal like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EBQm.png)

Can anyone help?

It randomly fixed itself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is the font installed? Did you set it in VS Code or check the config? Can you use the font in other applications?